# Doesn't $i=-i$ from the definition $i^2=-1$?

Tags: complex-numbers

There is 2 definition about imaginary numbers:-

1. Imaginary unit, $i=\sqrt{-1}$
2. The square of Imaginary unit, $i^2=-1$

But the later is used mostly, as known to me, because of many reasons. And my question is from the later(2nd) definition. Now consider this:-
$$      i^2=-1$$
$$=> (1) i=\sqrt{-1}   or
              (2) i=-\sqrt{-1}$$
Now,
$$     i=-\sqrt{-1}$$
$$=> i=-i    \text{   [from (1)]}$$

But actually $i$ cannot be equal to $-i$. So, where did I actually gone; where is my fault.

Comment: What are you doing in your second step, it's not clear.

Comment: 1 --> 2, but 2 -/-> 1. That is, it's not the plus of minus square root. When you "multiply by 'step 2' i", you aren't actually doing that. You assumed the plus or minus square root of i^2 is +/- i.

Comment: No, my question is a different question. I'm asking about why not $i=-i$; where is the contradiction? I know where is the fault in the question that you are saying, my question can be duplicate of.

Comment: The equation $x^2=-1$ has *two roots*, $\pm i$, just as $x^2=9$ has $\pm3$.

Comment: $1^2=1$. Does that make $-1=1$? By the way, I have a personal vendetta against your definition 1 because it hints that square roots and complex numbers work together. They don't. Also, formally, definition 2 is the only one we use (and the one which is easier to teach, yet still 1 is so commonly used in introduction classes).

Comment: @Berci  So that I asked the question.

Comment: @Arthur My question is using the 2nd definition not using the first one. Although $i=-i$ cannot be proved using the 1st definition.

Comment: What do you mean by $\sqrt{-1}$? It is not clear which complex number the expression $\sqrt{-1}$ refers to, since there are two complex numbers whose square is $-1$.

Comment: @littleO I think that's what he's asking: Are there really two of them? Are they actually different? (And of course they are, I know that.)

Answer (score 1):

You can replace $i$ with $-i$ and get exactly the same algebraic structure and since we have no reason to prefer one over the other we choose the one with less symbols.

Comment: Do you mean, in any way, $i=-i$. And that we can use either of the symbol anywhere in the calculation and that will not cause any problems or unmathematical things???

Comment: It means $\mathbb{R}[i]$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}[-i]$

Comment: @Curiouslearner Yes, if you replace them then everything still works exactly as you would expect. I bet with a little effort you can even prove this on your own.